# Deleted items from collection persist in local storage

Tags: backbone.js

I have a user model in backbone as follows

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({  
        initialize: function(){  

        },  
          defaults: {  
            firstname: '<FirstName>',  
            lastname: '<LastName>',  
            email: '<EmailAddress>'
        }  
    });
```

and collection:

```
UserCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model : User,
    localStorage:new Backbone.LocalStorage("UsersCollection")


  });
```

When I delete the model, I use the following code

```
    var model=this.collection.get(cid);
    this.collection.remove(model);
```

cId comes from the view, which i have not shown here. The model is removed from teh collection as I can render it just fine and the model is not there. (cid) is an attribute on the delete button.

Anyways, when I refresh the page, the deleted item reappearrs. Editing works fine. After refresign, the item isn't there anymore. Also, if I try to do `Collection.sync()`, I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined
```

`model.destroy()` gives an error too: A "url" property or function must be specified 
How do I remove the item from local storage

Answer (score 0):

You should always define either an url of collection or an url of model. 
Even if you are using only local storage.
Just try to specify url of collection as "/".

Comment: doesn't work. still getting an error when i specify url for collection. when i specify it for a model, a request is made, but model remains

Comment: I mean the item is not removed. It sends an ajax request tothe server to delete the model (which is pointlesss since the item is in localstorage). The item continues to persist in local storage. model.destroy doesn't work